# How to catch 'end of paper roll' event?

Tags: c#, thermal-printer

We got a POSX thermal printer printing a receipt from a C# apps, is there a way to know if the paper roll is empty?

The problem is that the printer cache the page asked to print so it can print half on the end of the first roll, then we switch paper roll and it print only the end of the receipt, I would want to have it all on 1 receipt.

Is there an event or something that could tell me the paper roll emptied?

Comment: Does the hardware itself send a signal back to the host computer? What model is it?

Comment: I'd say that entirely depends on the printer (hardware) and driver software

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

When using a low-level protocol (I believe POSX supports ESCPOS) you can send a status request to the printer periodically and the returned value will give you status information such as paper low, cover open, paper jam, status of connected devices if supported (e.g. cash drawer open/closed).

Or use a higher-level API such as OPOS / UnifiedPOS, which is much simpler and is widely used so gives your application some mesure of device independence.

Comment: I've read lot of article about this and they often say that the "status" returned is alway "ok" because alot of drivers do not update the status as they should, I've tested and even when the printer roll is removed it still return "ok" as result.